# how to set "app:backgroundTint" via style?

Tags: java, android, xml, styles, android-appcompat

I want to replace:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:backgroundTint = "..."
...
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

with

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/My.Bg.Snackbar.DayNight"
...
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

and

```
  <style name="My.Bg.Dark" parent="">
    <item name="app:backgroundTint">@color/og_background_dark</item>
  </style>
```

and

```
  <declare-styleable name="My">
    <!-- The background color. -->
    <attr name="app:backgroundTint" format="color" />
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

but I get an error:

```
error: resource app:attr/backgroundTint not found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
  <style name="My.Bg.Dark" parent="">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/og_background_dark</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: Still need to define in `<attr name="backgroundTint" format="color" />` ?

Answer (score 0):

just use this code

```
  <style name="MyStyleName" parent="">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/green</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: Still need to define in `<attr name="backgroundTint" format="color" /> `